# How to update out-of-date TF2 Server in Linux

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, linux

I have a TF2 server which was working, up until recently.

When I try to connect, it always says this:

> The server you are trying to connect to is running an older version of
>   the game.

I have tried...

- Turning on the `-autoupdate` flag: Did not work
- Manually running the update via `./steam -command update -game tf -dir ./tf -verify_all -retry`: Did not work
- sudo'ing the previous command
- Deleting `ClientRegistry.blob` in the `steam` folder and trying the above.

None of the above have worked. How can I get my TF2 server up to date?

Comment: When you say, do not work, what do you mean? You still get the same message? Or do the things you listed fail? I use the second method you listed, and it works every time.

Comment: I have tried the above, and still get the same message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> _restart

or

> quit

From my small experience of running tf2 servers I remember that you would need to reboot the server for it to kick off updates. 
Assuming you use the standard srcds_run Linux script, it should restart within 10 seconds.
If you are using a server provider and you are still hitting a brick wall talk to them :).

Answer (score 2):

This problem may be related to the **steam.inf** file not correctly updating.

Try removing it then retry an update (it's located in your *orangebox/tf* folder).

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the path to the Steam binary in order for the `-autoupdate` flag to work. Here’s how I do it:

```
./srcds_run -game tf -autoupdate -steambin /home/tf2server/hlds/steam +map koth_king
```